# Karate: How can I stop seeing Debug info on console using in intelij IDE

Tags: java, karate

Karate: How can I stop seeing Debug info on console using in intelij IDE

[image]

Comment: If you are running your app in Debug Mode, it WILL show. Other solution is to remove all `Log.*()` calls if you have them in your code OR Run your app in Release Mode.

Comment: I have found the solution that by logback-test.xml file of karate was missing from project and by default it was showing debug on intelij.Added the file and it have fixed the issue